# Re-rendering tiles after updating database using mapcache_seed

Tags: postgis, mapserver, mapcache, postgresql-10

I have developed the map using MapServer and pre-generated tile using mapcache. Now I have an idea to update the database every day. As changes apply in the database only those parts should be re-render and new tile should be generated. As changes are very small and rendering all ties from start is difficult to process.

I got expiry list of tiles by following osm2pgsql:

```
osm2pgsql --append --slim --cache 1000 --multi-geometry /home/parsis/diff_file_minute.xml --number-processes 2 --hstore -d testdemo -r xml -e6-11 -o /home/parsis/expire.list**
```

Got list something like this:

```
 - 11/329/713
 - 8/40/91
 - 10/164/357
 - 7/29/47
```

I find another approach using [render_expired](https://ircama.github.io/osm-carto-tutorials/manpage.html?url=https://rawgit.com/openstreetmap/mod_tile/master/docs/render_expired.1), but don't know how to use it with mapcache.

How is it possible using mapcache_seed?